# How do I get the maximum value for a text in a UNIX file as shown below?

Tags: unix

I have a unix file with the following contents.

```
$cat myfile.txt
abc:1
abc:2
hello:3
hello:6
wonderful:1
hai:2
hai:4
hai:8
```

How do I get the max value given for each text in the file above.

'abc' value 2
'hello' value 6
'hai' value 8
'womderful' 1

Comment: I am a little confused on which count you want. A sum of each unique word?  The last occurrence of a word? Can you explain?

Comment: agree, not clear wher value `abc 1` comes from  whenyour input has 2 lines that match abc AND the 2nd line says `abc 2` WHILE your output for `hello 6` is selecting the 2nd line of hello. AND your headline says "extract number after delimiter", I don't see that happening. Please clarify. Good luck.

Comment: I have edited the question. Sorry for confusing you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the current example in your question, minus the first line of expected output:

```
awk -F':' '{arr[$1]=$2 ; next} END {for (i in arr) {print i, arr[i]} } ' inputfile
```

You example input and expected output are very confusing....  The reason I posted this is to get feedback from the OP forthcoming

This assumes the data is unsorted, but also works with sorted data (New):

```
sort -t: -k2n inputfile | awk -F':' '{arr[$1]=$2 ; next} END {for (i in arr) {print i, arr[i]} } '
```